# How to reconcile Stripe checkout session and Payment Intent after payment?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Since the `Checkout session API` is not providing the `paymentIntent` id upon creation, how do I know if a user has successfully made the payment from Stripe's checkout URL?

How my app works:

1. User clicks on purchase now
2. A `Stripe Checkout session URL` will be generated with the `Checkout API`
3. After the payment, I will get the `paymentIntent` object from Stripe but how do I know if the payment has already been made successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using webhooks to determine that payment was received successfully. See: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders and https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks.